# Heroku build docker image with --no-cache option

Tags: python, docker, heroku

I'm trying to update a Docker image on my Heroku app.

I just used the following commands from this documentation article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

```
heroku login
heroku container:login
heroku container:push web
heroku container:release web
heroku open
```

This set of commands worked perfectly the first time, except that I got an error about not being able to map to the `$PORT` variable I figured out how to fix the problem (I'm using Flask), so I updated my `api.py` (I named it `api.py` instead of `app.py`), and now I want to push the updates to the Heroku app. But running through those commands, it seems to use the cache (I've had this problem on my local machine before; I have to use the `--no-cache` option when I buid). I don't really know when it's being built on Heroku.

Anyways, at the end of the release command, it says: `The process type web was not updated, because it is already running the specified docker image.`

How do I get it to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the people out there looking at this, it turned out it was a simple mistake in my Dockerfile.

Basically, I was using `git clone` to get my app files. Because of this, I had no `ADD` commands anywhere, so all the results were being cached by docker.

All I had to do was run `ADD` instead of `git clone` to import my project files, and now everything runs perfectly well :)